# How does C treat trailing spaces in scanf?

Tags: c, character, scanf

If a *scanf* statement has any white space in the format string, like as follows,

```
scanf(" %c",&abc);
```

then it just skips over an unlimited number of white spaces until it hits a character.
So **\n p** as input would store *p* in **abc**.

Using this concept I am not able to predict the output of the following program that I typed.

```
char echo ;
do {
       scanf ("%c ", &echo);
       printf ("%c\n",echo);
} while (echo != '\n') ;
```

Note that there is a *trailing space* in the scanf statement.

Upon execution of the code I get the following behaviour.
It asks for a character. *I enter C*
It asks for a character. *I enter I*
It prints C.
It asks for a character. *I enter R*
It prints I.
It asks for a character. *I enter C*
It prints R.

This goes on forever. If I press newline, then it just skips it.
Why does it ask for two characters in the beginning? Shouldn't it execute the *printf* statement?
Why is the character of the previous input get printed in the next one?

Comment: @xing so if there isn't any white space, then it would 'wait' for white space?

Comment: I fail to see how your posted code corresponds to your description of the behavior. I see no code asking for a character.

Comment: @EOF the scanf statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: @SmarthBansal `scanf()` *scans* input. It does not ask for it.

Comment: @EOF I see what you mean. By saying it asks for a character I mean that it waits for the user to enter something.

Comment: "It asks for a character" **how??** try `printf("\n==> "); fflush(stdout);` right before the `scanf()`.

Comment: @pmg I don't understand. It clearly asks for input?

Comment: Rather than a simple blinking cursor as input prompt, try my suggestion.

Comment: @pmg wow! Thanks, you solved my problem! Summarizing: It checks for non-whites only after I press *enter* during the execution of the scanf. If it doesn't find any, then it waits for the next *enter*. Right?

Comment: Kind of ... `scanf("%c ", &ch);` reads a character and skips 0 or more whitespace. You type "3ENTER" and you're still stuck inside `scanf()` ignoring whitespace. You type a few more ENTERs (TABs, SPACEs) and you're still stuck inside `scanf()`. When finally you type "7ENTER", `scanf()` gets out of ignoring whitespace (leaving the "7ENTER" in the input buffer) and the program continues.

Comment: @pmg Thanks! Should I delete this question? I now understand how poorly worded it is.

Answer (score 2):

In `scanf` format the space character matches any amount of white space (spaces, tabs and newlines) in the input.

So you enter `C + newline` and nothing happens, as `scanf` matched the character `C` to `%c` and the `newline` is eaten by the space. But `scanf` will continue until it gets something which does not match. So you can put any amount of spaces, tabs and newlines here.

When `scanf` reads somewhing that does not match, it calls `ungetc(c, stdin)` to put it back to stdin and returns. So the space will continue matching until you put something different.

That's why the last `scanf` returns when you type `R + newline`. Then the next `scanf` executes, it matches `R` with `%c` and the newline with space. But space is still matching any number whitespaces. It will end when you type a non white-space character.