# I can't seem to figure out why scanf in my code is acting so weird

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

# define ListSize 100

typedef int DataType;
typedef struct {
DataType elem[ListSize];
int length;
}SqList;


SqList * createList(int n) 
{
    SqList *L;
    int i;
    L=(SqList *)malloc(sizeof(SqList));
    L->length=0;
    printf("Input the elements:\n");

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ",&(L->elem[i]));
        L->length++;
    }
    return L;
}


void display(SqList *L)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < L->length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t" , L->elem[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}

int insert(SqList *L, int mark, DataType x)//Insert element x into list in the position mark
{
    int i=0;
    if(mark>L->length||mark<0) 
    return 0;
    else
    {
        for (i=L->length-1;i>=mark;i--)
        L->elem[i+1] = L->elem[i]; //move elements
        L->elem[i+1]=x; //insert
        L->length++;
        return 1;
        
    }
}

void main()
{
    int num;
    int in,loc;
    SqList *List;
    printf("Input the number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    List=createList(num);
    printf("\n The list is: \n");
    display(List);
    printf("Please input location and element to insert into the list: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&loc,&in);

    insert(List,loc,in);
    display(List);
}
```

So my assignment was to create a sequential list and insert an element into the user typed position in the list. I came up with the above code but my scanf function is acting weird. It asks me to type in the number of elements I want in the list but for some reason it takes one more input that it should. And that input actually goes to the value of variable loc. I can't seem to understand why it's working like that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output / behavior you get and the expacted output / behavior.

Comment: is that because of `scanf("%d %d",&loc,&in); <- this makes input go to the value of variable loc?

Comment: *Thou shalt not use `scanf` without checking the return value!* Never ever! If you check the return value you might find that the first calls after `scanf("%d",&num);` and `scanf("%d %d",&loc,&in);` will not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line
`scanf("%d ",&(L->elem[i]));` in `createList`.  Specifically, the trailing space in the format string `"%d "` is consuming the carriage return when you enter the first number and you must type something else for the first call to `scanf` to complete.  So when you think you're entering the second element, you're actually still giving input to the first `scanf` call.  For more details on spaces in `scanf` format string, see this answer.

[How does C treat trailing spaces in scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844751/how-does-c-treat-trailing-spaces-in-scanf)

Simply remove the trailing space `"%d"` and it will work as you intended.

Comment: Rather than _consuming the carriage return_ we should say _consuming any amount of white space_.

Comment: I would suggest to move the space to the front of the string to consume some `\n` left over from `scanf("%d",&num);` and other function calls in `main`.